# How to fix or remove extra black space at the bottom? iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, ios15

I just updated my phone to iOS 15 and this black space at the bottom displayed (see picture below).

The black screen appeared when I tap input field and I scroll at the bottom.

---

I tried to wrap the contents with `100vh` as what from the related issue that I found on internet. But still same, it does not work.

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div style="100vh !important;">
            // contents here
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's the sample image (iPhone SE).
[image]